# Java File - Open A File And Write To It

Tags: java, file

I know we are supposed to add a snipit of code to our questions, but I am seriously dumbfounded and can't wrap my head or find any examples to follow from.

Basically I want to open file **C:\A.txt** , which already has contents in it, and write a string at the end. Basically like this.

File A.txt contains:

```
John
Bob
Larry
```

I want to open it and write Sue at the end so the file now contains:

```
John
Bob
Larry
Sue
```

Sorry for no code example, my brain is dead this morning....

Comment: Oh this post is on geek-and-poke!
http://geek-and-poke.com/geekandpoke/2013/11/10/indirection

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Please Search [Google](http://www.google.com) given to the world by Larry Page and Sergey Brin.

```
BufferedWriter out = null;

try {
    FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("out.txt", true); //true tells to append data.
    out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
    out.write("\nsue");
}

catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}

finally {
    if(out != null) {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I checked Google first and it led me here ;)

Answer (score 13):

Suggestions:

- Create a [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) object that refers to the already existing file on disk.
- Use a [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) object, and use the constructor that takes the File object and a boolean, the latter if `true` would allow appending text into the File if it exists.
- Then initialize a [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) passing in the FileWriter into its constructor.
- Then call `println(...)` on your PrintWriter, writing your new text into the file.
- As always, close your resources (the PrintWriter) when you are done with it.
- As always, don't ignore exceptions but rather catch and handle them.
- The `close()` of the PrintWriter should be in the try's finally block.

e.g.,

```
  PrintWriter pw = null;

  try {
     File file = new File("fubars.txt");
     FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
     pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
     pw.println("Fubars rule!");
  } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
     if (pw != null) {
        pw.close();
     }
  }
```

Easy, no?

Answer (score 4):

To expand upon Mr. Eels comment, you can do it like this:

```
    File file = new File("C:\\A.txt");
    FileWriter writer;
    try {
        writer = new FileWriter(file, true);
        PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter(writer);
        printer.append("Sue");
        printer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Don't say we ain't good to ya!

Comment: 1+ to ya, but don't forget to close the print writer in the finally block, not in the try block. You don't want any dangling resources. See my example to see what I mean.