# get int numbers zero to nine one by one java

Tags: java, digits

Hello i would like to know the best and easiest way to scan an int number from a txt file
one digit after another 
the numbers i can find is 0 to 9
non else
for example:

```
24351235312531135
```

i want to get each time im scanning these inputs

```
2 
4
3
5
1
2
```

EDIT:

```
My input in txt file is something like this
 13241235135135135
 15635613513513531
 13513513513513513
 13251351351351353
 13245135135135315
 13513513513513531
```

6 lines with a known number of digits
    ....
i have found this code but is not working

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ScannerReadFile {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Location of file to read
    File file = new File("data.txt");

    try {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        scanner.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

im unable to find the exact query im facing

Comment: Which one is your input? a One-line number of lines of numbers?

Comment: `im unable to find the exact query im facing` this is disappointing. What do you mean by your code is not working ? What output/error your are getting ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("data.txt");
    try {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
                System.out.println(line.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need a for loop :

```
for(int i=0;i<line.length();i++)
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(line.charAt(i)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this example on how to open and read a file in Java:
http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/how-open-read-file-java-string-array-list

Check also this SO question: [Java File - Open A File And Write To It](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667734/java-file-open-a-file-and-write-to-it)

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the characters for each line:

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
   String line = scanner.nextLine();
      for (char c: line.toCharArray()) {
        System.out.println(c);
      }
}
```